# Segmentation fault (Core dumped) issue when running my code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, coredump

Piece of homework I'm working on and I can't figure out why that when I try to run my program, it gives the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped). Have been trying for a while and I can't see where I went wrong. I researched segmentation faults and went through my code line by line but I still dont know. Still pretty new to coding in c++.

```
//This program reads the last names of the candidates and the number of votes they receive. The\
 program sorts and outputs the candidates based on votes received in descending order.

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void openFile(ifstream&);
void getData(ifstream&, string [], int [], int &);
void computePercentages(int[], double [], int &);
void sortVotes(string [], int [], double [], int);
int findSmallestIndex(const int[], int, int);

const int SIZE = 30;

int main(){

   string name[SIZE];
   double percentages[SIZE];
   int votes[SIZE];
   int size, sum;
   ifstream in;

openFile(in);
   getData(in, name, votes, size);
   computePercentages(votes, percentages, sum);
   sortVotes(name, votes, percentages, size);
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      cout << name[i] << " " << votes[i] << " " << setprecision(4) << percentages[i] << endl;

   in.close();

   return (0);


}

void openFile(ifstream& in){
   string filename;
   cout << "Enter file name: ";
   cin >> filename;
   in.open(filename.c_str());
}

void getData(ifstream& in, string n[], int v[],int& s){
   int x = 0;
   for (int s = 0; s < SIZE; s++){
      n[s] = x;
      v[s] = x;
   }
   in >> n[s] >> v[s];
   while (!in.eof()){
      s++;
      in >> n[s] >> v[s];
   }
}

void computePercentages(int v[], double p[], int& sum){
   int total = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      total = total + v[i];

   double factor = 100.0 / total;
   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)

      p[i] = factor * v[i];
}
void sortVotes(string n[], int v[], double p[],int s){
   for(int index = 0; s - 1; index++){
      int smallestIndex = findSmallestIndex(v, s, index)
      swap (n[index], n[smallestIndex]);
      swap (v[index], v[smallestIndex]);
      swap (p[index], p[smallestIndex]);
   }}

int findSmallestIndex(const int v[], int s, int start){
   int smallestIndex = start;
   for (int i = start +1; i < s; i++)
      if (v[i] < v[smallestIndex])
         smallestIndex = i;
   return smallestIndex;
}

void swap(string &a, string &b){
   string temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = temp;
}
void swap(int &a, int &b){
   int temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = temp;
}

void swap(double &a, double &b){
   double temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = temp;
}
```

Like I said, I dont know where I'm going wrong here. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: When you call the `getData` function, what is the value of the variable `size`?

Comment: the size variable that is passed to getdata is not initaltized and used soo

Comment: You have two different `s` variables in `getData`.  This is the danger of using one-letter variable names instead of descriptive names.  What is `s` supposed to mean?  You do the same for `n`, `v`, etc.  Variable names do not cost anything per-letter.

Comment: You don't set `size` with an initial value. That means it could be anything.

Comment: Maybe the OP was hoping that the `s` in `getData` would set the `size` variable, since it is passed by reference.  Of course you see that isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, the first loop sets 's' to SIZE, and your array lengths are both 'SIZE' as well.

```
 void getData(ifstream& in, string n[], int v[],int& s){
       int x = 0;
       for (int s = 0; s < SIZE; s++){
          n[s] = x;
          v[s] = x;
       }
       in >> n[s] >> v[s];
       while (!in.eof()){
          s++;
          in >> n[s] >> v[s];
       }
    }
```

The second loop (while) continues to increment 's' (so now s > SIZE), which causes and invalid array access when you execute `in >> n[s] >> v[s];` , since `n[s]` and `v[s]` now access past the memory allocated for your arrays of length SIZE.

Also, since this is C++, use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: Maybe the OP's error is `for (int s` when it should be `for (s`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i think this would just shadow the input argument `int& s`.

Comment: @SmexxyMoose Depends on what you are trying to do, which is tough to infer from your code.